# I want to run one feature file on 5 chrome sessions in parallel in protractor cucumber framework

Tags: protractor, cucumber, config

sharedFiles= true is not an option as It breaks down the feature files for parallel execution.

I want to run one feature file on multiple chrome sessions in parallel.
How to do that?

Comment: too vague... what's feature file? a single spec dedicated to test one particular feature? And how `sharedFiles=true` breaks this file? What error do you get?

Comment: have you tried `multiCapbilities` and without setting `sharedFiles=true`

Comment: Yes using 2 multicapabilities objects, I am able to launch 2 chrome browsers. But scenario only gets executed on one chrome and other chrome browser quits after launching.

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** run one feature file on multiple chrome sessions in parallel with protractor.

With protractor you can [run your tests in parallel when you enable sharding. The files are executed across different browsers as they become available.](https://www.protractortest.org/#/style-guide)

You should spread your tests to different files and add to your protractor.conf :

```
shardTestFiles: true,
maxInstances: /**number of how much instances you want*/
```